# Function called twice whilst loading Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have turned one of my manual scripts into a backend using flask. If I am to run this script from the terminal for testing it `python3 app.py`, it runs the `checkRouter()` function twice. I am not sure why this is happening, can someone please advise me?

```py
import buttonshim
import datetime
import flask
import json
import subprocess
import threading
import time


routerCheck  = ""
script       = ""
switchButton = True
switchCheck  = True


thisJson = {
    "thisName": "none",
    "thisTime": "0",
    "executed": ""
}




## Script
def blinkButton():
    def run():
        while (switchButton == True):
            buttonshim.set_pixel(0x00, 0xff, 0x00)
            time.sleep(.2)
            buttonshim.set_pixel(0,0,0)
            time.sleep(.2)
            if switchButton == False:
                break
            if script.poll() is not None:
                switchButton == False
                break
    thread = threading.Thread(target=run)
    thread.start()

def blinkButtonCheck():
    def run():
        while (switchCheck == True):
            buttonshim.set_pixel(0x00, 0x00, 0xff)
            time.sleep(.2)
            buttonshim.set_pixel(0,0,0)
            time.sleep(.2)
            if switchCheck == False:
                break
            if routerCheck.poll() is not None:
                switchCheck == False
                break
    thread = threading.Thread(target=run)
    thread.start()

def switchOn():
    global switchButton
    global script
    global thisJson
    try:
        if script.poll() is None:
            script.kill()
            switchButton = False
    except:
        print("Process still running, killing...")
    finally:
        print("switchButton on")
        if thisJson["thisName"] == "none":
            print("No name set")
        else:
            switchButton         = True
            thisJson["executed"] = str(datetime.datetime.now())
            script               = subprocess.Popen(['/home/flask/run.sh', thisJson["thisName"], thisJson["thisTime"]])
            blinkButton()

def switchOff():
    global switchButton
    global script
    global thisJson
    try:
        print("switchButton off")
        switchButton = False
        script.kill()
        buttonshim.set_pixel(0xff, 0x00, 0x00)
        time.sleep(2)
        buttonshim.set_pixel(0,0,0)
        thisJson = {
            "thisName": "none",
            "thisTime": "0",
            "executed": ""
        }
    except:
        print("Process not running")
        thisJson = {
            "thisName": "none",
            "thisTime": "0",
            "executed": ""
        }

def checkChannel():
    global switchCheck
    global routerCheck
    try:
        if routerCheck.poll() is None:
            routerCheck.kill()
            switchCheck = False
    except:
        print("Process still running, killing...")
    finally:
        print("switchCheck on")
        switchCheck = True
        routerCheck = subprocess.Popen(['/home/flask/run.sh', 'check'])
        blinkButtonCheck()

# run router check every half hour
def checkRouter():
    print("Initial router check")
    def runCheck():
        while True:
            checkChannel()
            time.sleep(1800)
    threadCheck = threading.Thread(target=runCheck)
    threadCheck.start()





## Flask
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/get', methods=['GET'])
def get():
    global thisJson
    print("\n{}\nOBJECTMAKER: {}\n".format(datetime.datetime.now(), thisJson))
    return json.dumps(thisJson)

@app.route('/api/<set>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def kill(set):
    global thisJson
    content  = flask.request.json
    print(content)
    thisJson["thisName"] = content["thisName"]
    thisJson["thisTime"] = content["thisTime"]
    switchOn()
    return json.dumps(True)


@app.route('/api/stop', methods=['POST'])
def stop():
    switchOff()
    return json.dumps(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    checkRouter()
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5001, debug=True)
```

As you can see from below, `Initial router check` and `switchCheck on` is printed twice, meaning it gets called twice. Before wrapping Flask around it I never had this issue, but I was using a basic `pause()` at the end, after loading buttons scripts (removed from this new script). Note, `sudo` is required for `buttonshim` to work properly.

```
└─$ sudo python3 ./app.py
Initial router check
Process still running, killing...
switchCheck on
Killing wireless processes
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on

 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5001/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
Initial router check
Process still running, killing...
switchCheck on
Killing wireless processes
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 171-605-250

^C^CException ignored in: <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1567, in _shutdown
    lock.acquire()
KeyboardInterrupt:
```

Comment: interesting... are you sure run.sh doesnt execute the app.py file again? we might have to look at this code - if you are sure it's completely unrelated, you may as well exclude it from your question. are you opening app.py via console? it might also be your IDE spawning another instance

Comment: i'm 100% confident `run.sh` does not execute `app.py` again.  i am executing `app.py` from my zsh terminal. using `ps -aux` i can see multiple instances of `run.sh` executing, but as you can see from the log output, even before it runs that, the `checkRouter()` shows it was executed twice. so the issue is well before `run.sh` executes. it's within Python script.

Answer (score 0):

What I tried and solved the issue is to use a WSGI instead of the debug one that flask provides. For example, instead of running your app with `python app.py`, I used `gunicorn app:app` more on gunicorn configuration can be found [here](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html). For that to work you also need to add `checkRouter()` outside the `if __name__ == '__main__':` (I know this sounds like a bad practice, but if you run it with gunicorn it does not go through `__main__`).

Comment: I removed the `debug=True`, and it fixed the issue. not sure what the go is, but it's as if a file is modified and thus it re-runs the flask server. I'm not sure if that's directly related to your last comment about threads; if it was I would mark this is as correct. Thoughts?

Comment: It's just a guess, and since I am not familiar with the default debug server implementation, I will remove it from the answer.